# Carry content to next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does javascript facilitate carrying content across to another page and thereafter doing some actions. I havent been able to find any relevant commands that allow me to execute actions on a redirected page.

Essentially, I am after the following (example of usecase):

- Page is a generator that creates a simple text sentence based on some
  criteria a user selects
- Once the user clicks 'Go', page redirects to
  another page that has a single text box and button
- Automatically populates this textbox with the content and submits

Is this possible?

Comment: You could maybe use things like GET and Post perhaps?

Comment: If it's on the same domain, even cookies or localstorage might work

Comment: You can used `querystring` using javascript you get content on next page

Comment: You can use `querystring`, `localstorage` or `cookies`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Javascript to redirect the user to the new page, you can set global variables of the new window like so,

```
// Save the reference to the new window in a variable
var redirect = window.open('http://www.example.com');

//form the variables as an object
var variables = {
    var1: "First Value",
    var2: "Second Value",
    ...
}

// Send the variables to new page
redirect.variables = myVariables;
```

And then in the new page you can just do

```
console.log(window.variables.var1); //will give "First Value"
console.log(window.variables.var2); //will give "Second Value"
```

Comment: Thanks Jay. However, I would need to have javascript on the next page which one right? There is no way to load this into a 'cache' per se